# Database connectivity issue in Mule4.2.0

Tags: jdbc, mule, mysql-connector, mule4

We are facing a  MySQL database connectivity issue in Mulesoft, the mule has two types of database transactions. one is to the mule’s server( Self ) database and another one is to the remote server database.

Recently we upgraded MyQL 5.7 to 8.0 in the remote server, After that the mule database transaction within the server (Self) is fine and we are facing an issue on the remote server. We checked the log details and it shows like

```
Message               : Cannot get connection for URL jdbc:mysql://xx.xxx.xxx.xx:xxxx/{data_base_name}?logger=org.mule.extension.db.api.logger.MuleMySqlLogger : Could not create a connection to database server.
Error type            : DB:CONNECTIVITY
```

In our investigation, we believe that this issue is due to the JDBC driver compatibility issue( Mule 4.2.0 with MySQL 8.0).

Please share your thoughts on this.

How can we resolve this? if the issue is due to the JDBC driver we like to update which is compatibile to both MySQL versions (5.7 and 8.0)

Comment: Why don't you update the jdbc drivers in your test / pre-prod environment and see what happens.

Comment: @Shadow We are looking into it.

Comment: @Shadow We are not sure which version is compatible with both MySQL versions. Do you know anything about this?

Comment: This is a MySQL JDBC driver question unrelated to Mule.

Comment: The current version mysql jdbc driver that you can download from mysql's website is compatible with both versions of mysql.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is right there in the documentation: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/connectors/en/connector-j-versions.html

> MySQL Server versions: Connector/J 8.0 supports MySQL 5.7, 8.0, 8.1, and 8.0.

Comment: I have changed the JDBC driver version in the pom.xml file. Do any additional changes need to be done on the server? like upgrading the existing microservices or need to install any additional package.

Also how it will impact on the existing mule?

Comment: We don't know how your applications and infrastructure are organized so we would not know the answer.

Comment: @rahulrj again, test it and you will see.

Comment: @aled
After applying the required changes made in the code , we have deployed the code in the server and got an warning message like " WARN  2024-02-06 10:24:08,835 [WrapperListener_start_runner] [event: ] org.mule.extension.db.internal.domain.connection.mysql.MySqlConnectionParameters: Unable to attach Mule Logger to MySql Driver. Cause: com/mysql/jdbc/log/Log "

Comment: That's a different issue.

Comment: @aled any thoughts on the above warning

Comment: Please open a new question for the new issue.